# Debezium Outbox Error for Spring Kafka Project

Tags: spring-boot, apache-kafka, docker-compose, apache-kafka-connect, debezium

I am trying to connect 2 microservices using Kafka Connector in Spring using Docker containers.

Refer to this [Gitlab link](https://gitlab.com/oawofolu/ssmdemo) for project details.

I have 2 containers in Spring.

1. **s1-pledgeservice**
2. **s1-donorservice**

First, I need to run **s1-pledgeservice** (through `startup.sh` in the corresponding project folder) and it works fine.

Second, I run for the second step, when I run **s1-donorservice** (through `startup.sh` in the corresponding project folder), and it works fine.

Third, when I run `./register_connectors.sh` in **s1-pledgeservice**, I get the following error:

```json
{
  "error_code": 400,
  "message": "Connector configuration is invalid and contains the following 2 error(s):
         \nInvalid value io.debezium.transforms.Filter for configuration transforms.outbox.type: Class io.debezium.transforms.Filter could not be found.
         \nInvalid value null for configuration transforms.outbox.type: Not a Transformation\nYou can also find the above list of errors at the endpoint `/connector-plugins/{connectorType}/config/validate`"
}
```

Running **s1-pledge-service** gives the following exception:

```
kafka-connect    | 2020-12-23 08:16:43,906 ERROR  ||  Uncaught exception in REST call to /connectors/   [org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.rest.errors.ConnectExceptionMapper]
kafka-connect    | javax.ws.rs.NotAllowedException: HTTP 405 Method Not Allowed
```

Is there a debezium filter pom.xml dependency that is required?

Note that I am running Docker from a Debian distribution in WSL2.

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me that you are using Debezium 1.1.2 while the transformation you are trying to use was added only at 1.2.x.